# Cannot translate Wagtail ChooserBlock

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-localize

I have a block that contains a field of type 'ChooserBlock'. Once I sync the page to other locales, I am not able to edit this field for locales other than the default one. The field says:
["Uses english version"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCahY.png)

I should be able to select a different option. For instance, different Chooser blocks allow me to select a different option, such as the [PageChooseBlock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4D5N.png)

Comment: Are you wanting the choice translated or to be able to make a separate choice on the translation?

Comment: @RichardAllen I want to make a separate choice. That or be able to not select any option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you're using wagtail-localize ...

You can add or remove fields from the translatable set using the translatable_fields list of the model/page. For you, you could force your choice field to be translatable with:

```
translatable_fields = translatable_fields + [
    TranslatableField('some_choice_field'),
]
```

BUT this probably won't give you what you're hoping for since the input field for that on translation page will just be a simple input field without choice widget.

I'm not sure if it's a translation of the option chosen on the source page that you want, or if it's the ability to choose an entirely different option.

If it's a translation, then you can use a custom translation model that takes a token ID and a locale then returns text for that locale (this is how I handle static text in templates for my sites).

If you want to be able to select different options per local, you might be better using a snippet model to store your options which you can filter based on locale.